# Ubuntu 12.04 will not connect to school wifi?

Tags: wireless, internet, intel, connection, intel-wireless

I am new to ubuntu.  My wireless card is a Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 (rev 57).  It will connect fine at my house, but not at school and some other places.  The networks which I cannot connect to are WPA/WPA2 personal and WPA/WPA2 enterprise.

Comment: I had this issue in an old version of puppy Linux.  It seemed to be related to the encryption type and certain Intel cards.  You might do a search string to see if it is indeed an Intel driver issue.

Comment: WPA2 Enterprise often works a bit differently than other networks. You sometimes have to download a some certificates and tell the wireless manager where they are to pass authentication. Also, make sure the wireless network is saved in Ubuntu as WPA2 and not as WEP by accident - it might not immediately recognize the security type for whatever reason.